# Fixed header, centered scrollable body with max width and scrollbar to the side with paddingY

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building a react app with flexbox and I'm struggling getting all the pieces as I want them.

I want a fixed header at the top with a body that has its content centered and that can be scrolled (the scrollbar has to start in the body, not the header). This body can't go to the edges of the page so I'm using max-width to prevent this. The problem is that when I use the max-width, the scrollbar gets placed next to the body and it looks awful. I want it to stay at the far right of the page. Finally I want some space between the end of the body and the page (a bit of padding, if you will) so the content doesn't look like it's getting cut with the end of the site.

I've done this mockup in Photoshop

[image]

I mostly got the code working, minus the max-width and bottom padding. Here's what I got:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  background: white;
  height: 50px;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

- 

```
<div id="container">
    <header>top</header>
    <main>
      ...
    </main>
 </div>
```

I understand that this question has been asked in multiple ways a lot of times, but I've been looking for a while and I can't find the right one that fixes every thing I need.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add another element within the `<main>` tag. I use a `<div>` tag in my example, but it could be whatever you want. Keep the

```css
overflow: auto;
```

on the `<main>` tag, so when the inner div overflows, you can scroll the `<main>` tag to move the `<div>`

Here's an example where I added some background color to show separation and some [Lorem Ipsum text](https://www.lipsum.com/):

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  background: white;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#stuff {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: pink;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  flex: 1;
}

main {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <header>top</header>
    <main>
      <div id="stuff">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut nec magna porta, commodo magna ut, porta erat. Phasellus tristique leo vitae ante efficitur, sed fermentum mi auctor. In condimentum mi a urna cursus vestibulum. Nunc posuere metus turpis, faucibus viverra purus aliquam nec. Curabitur ultrices, sem nec aliquet congue, ligula justo sagittis arcu, quis blandit urna sem nec sem. Cras accumsan, turpis ac placerat porta, libero ex semper tellus, non mattis dui ligula id odio. Cras lobortis ex in ex consequat, eu viverra nibh luctus. Nulla facilisi. Nulla odio arcu, suscipit eu dui eget, cursus sodales ipsum. Nulla vestibulum nisl eget ante pellentesque, vel porttitor magna dapibus. Suspendisse at ligula nunc. Phasellus scelerisque urna sit amet scelerisque pharetra. Quisque risus metus, tincidunt vitae ultricies in, convallis tempus justo. Sed finibus laoreet dolor sit amet tincidunt. Sed efficitur volutpat aliquet.

Suspendisse condimentum euismod quam id tempor. Vestibulum rhoncus metus eu tortor rhoncus eleifend. Nam sagittis ex ex, eget varius ante semper a. Aenean vulputate eget ligula vel sodales. Vivamus vel nisi dignissim, eleifend sem non, bibendum dolor. Ut pulvinar malesuada nisi sit amet suscipit. Sed ultrices maximus tellus, nec congue felis.

Duis urna orci, consequat et lacinia lobortis, varius sed sem. Ut auctor congue augue quis interdum. Morbi erat justo, venenatis ac imperdiet sit amet, cursus eget tellus. Quisque accumsan nibh a dui vulputate tincidunt. Aenean accumsan diam lorem, ac rutrum magna ullamcorper et. Proin volutpat dolor tristique scelerisque tempus. Donec eu neque non purus pulvinar bibendum sed vitae justo. Suspendisse luctus dolor neque, eu convallis tortor condimentum ac. Aliquam sollicitudin ex ut sollicitudin sagittis. Aliquam imperdiet, diam vel hendrerit iaculis, neque ex accumsan neque, in hendrerit risus massa convallis ante. Cras urna velit, cursus sed dignissim vitae, porttitor faucibus est. Vestibulum ut dolor aliquam, malesuada velit ut, vestibulum nibh. Maecenas at convallis ex, a aliquam dui. Mauris at eros sit amet leo gravida pulvinar.

Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc faucibus laoreet ipsum, facilisis facilisis quam ultrices et. Vivamus interdum ut tortor sit amet sollicitudin. Cras rhoncus blandit lectus sed maximus. Integer ac dui nec metus dignissim lobortis vel vel erat. Cras in dignissim arcu. Nunc vulputate mi turpis, at dignissim turpis ullamcorper vitae. Cras neque justo, sagittis ut tempus vitae, pellentesque a mi.

Duis vehicula eros erat, vel tincidunt ante aliquet eget. Ut malesuada, est a sollicitudin tincidunt, magna ante varius est, vitae pulvinar arcu neque sit amet magna. Sed sit amet erat fermentum, bibendum ex sed, dictum lorem. Ut aliquam nibh vitae tellus convallis, sed condimentum augue suscipit. Nunc ac tellus sem. Maecenas vitae finibus lorem. Ut et fringilla lacus. Morbi neque lacus, rhoncus non odio et, sodales ultrices erat. Pellentesque molestie et felis sit amet pharetra. Curabitur id lacinia dolor. Curabitur non dignissim lorem, eleifend posuere lorem. Aliquam orci felis, vulputate vel felis molestie, vestibulum tempor tellus. Quisque mollis mauris blandit posuere tincidunt. Suspendisse condimentum est at enim interdum condimentum.

Aliquam a risus cursus, pretium dui nec, consectetur elit. Sed sollicitudin consectetur magna id accumsan. Quisque interdum tristique diam, at porta orci condimentum ut. Curabitur in metus purus. Donec diam orci, volutpat eu rhoncus in, accumsan sed neque. Nam egestas vestibulum vestibulum. Mauris fringilla, enim in finibus hendrerit, metus urna finibus lacus, in dictum eros eros vel orci. Aliquam blandit elit sem, vel fringilla libero commodo eu. Cras euismod a mauris non malesuada. Aliquam luctus malesuada nisl sed efficitur. Mauris suscipit convallis venenatis. Ut varius velit vitae scelerisque fermentum. Donec luctus convallis hendrerit. Sed vestibulum, diam at euismod lacinia, dolor eros commodo lacus, vitae pellentesque dui metus vel leo.

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam massa lectus, fermentum non dolor eu, auctor luctus ex. Duis posuere sit amet lorem ut commodo. Pellentesque ultrices in tortor vel dignissim. Quisque lorem nibh, ullamcorper in sem nec, rhoncus posuere tortor. Aenean vitae feugiat nisi. Proin elementum sollicitudin iaculis. Morbi nec erat volutpat, posuere augue quis, porttitor erat. Aliquam dignissim blandit laoreet. Donec consectetur a risus et varius. Suspendisse quis vulputate tellus.

Nunc eget erat id lacus dictum viverra. Vivamus vel vehicula ipsum. Fusce convallis leo diam, sed consectetur nulla sagittis rutrum. Curabitur nec ligula convallis ex rutrum fermentum. Donec auctor, erat quis euismod maximus, sem massa fermentum tortor, non scelerisque nibh nisi at arcu. Vivamus sodales fermentum nisi quis tempus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

Nunc et lacus ac augue tincidunt pellentesque. Sed at odio at sem lobortis vestibulum. Sed cursus augue et sapien eleifend tempor. Etiam suscipit mi non est vehicula tincidunt a vitae libero. In blandit fringilla lectus non dignissim. In interdum, nisl non suscipit sagittis, sem erat sagittis ex, quis egestas lorem tellus nec metus. Suspendisse suscipit ultrices nunc eget vulputate. Donec mollis condimentum massa. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce eget urna ut dui fringilla faucibus et id justo.

Suspendisse posuere justo eget bibendum venenatis. Pellentesque sollicitudin nisi augue. Nunc sed justo ac mi ultrices elementum sit amet non lorem. Maecenas accumsan vehicula urna, sit amet posuere dolor malesuada at. Morbi vitae mi sed est suscipit euismod. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla elit purus, elementum at odio eget, tempor efficitur leo. Nunc dapibus erat nec faucibus rhoncus. Curabitur accumsan nibh sit amet sagittis placerat. Donec mollis metus eu metus eleifend ornare. 
      </div>
    </main>
 </div>
```